# How to force universal app on iPad into scale mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I created an universal iOS app. On all iPhone variants I want native resolution without scaling, so I created splash screen images for all available sizes in `images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage` and set them all in Xcode:

[image: splash screen setup in xcode]

Now, this works very well for all iPhone versions up to the biggest iPhone 6 Plus.

On iPad (with high pixel density) though I don't want native resolution. Instead I want it to scale the app (even if it looks a bit blurry then, but that's ok).

How would I do that?

Comment: What do you mean? There is no scaling on the iPad. Not counting the upcoming iPad Pro, there is only one screen size for all iPads - 1024x768. Plus the retina version at 2048x1536. So what scaling do you mean?

Comment: @rmaddy Nope, if you don't explicitly support iPad, it will just scale up the iPhone version of the app

Comment: But you specifically stated that you have a universal app. So there is no scaling. If you want an iPhone-only app that runs in iPhone-compatibility mode on iPads, then don't make your app universal.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, I just found out for myself. That was the solution :) I always thought that if I set device target to iPhone then the app wouldn't be available for iPad at all but that's not the case. Instead, the app will just scale up and that's what I wanted, thanks. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll gladly mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite easy, I simply changed project type from "universal" to "iphone" and that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

In image assets you have to provide proper size for each launch screen, You can not use the same image for two devices in launch-images ( unless you have two copies of the same image ).

If you want to make app-size smaller, implement launch screen, set its background color to your desired background color and put your logo in the center of it. You can now remove iPhone 6,6Plus images from image assets, but you still have to provide launch images for iOS 7 devices (old iPhones / iPad ).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the Asset Catalogue. Create a LaunchScreen.xib , add a UIImage inside the view. Open the attribute inspector in the right hand panel and set the view mode to Aspect Fill.